# How to adjust j in `[.data.table` without breaking data.table's custom evaluation?

Tags: r, data.table, r-s3

I'm trying to extend `data.table` to [speed up/standardize analyses of complex survey designs](https://github.com/dcaseykc/dtsurvey). To do so, I'm trying to add a light layer on top of `[.data.table` where I intercept the call in `j` and in a few circumstances replace the operation (e.g. the `mean` to `median`) when special survey type commands are needed (or use normal functions when special ones are no needed to take advantage of `data.table`'s geforce type optimizations).

Based on my partial understanding of s3 dispatch, `NextMethod` should be the appropriate function here, but it seems to be passing `j` as the symbol `j` (e.g. `a[, j]` instead of `a[, median(v1)]` which interacts weirdly with data.table's NSE. I've tried versions with do.call, but couldn't get past some infinite recursion nonsense (`do.call('[', ...)` will endlessly dispatch `[.dtsurvey`)

Is there a clean way to adjust the arguments and pass it on to `data.table`? In the toy example below, I'd like to have the call return the `median` of column `v1` even though the initial operation is `mean`.

```r
library('data.table')

a = data.table(v1 = 1:10)
b = copy(a)

"[.dtsurvey" <- function(x, i, j, by, ...){
  
  j = substitute(j)
  print(j)
  if(j[[1]] == 'mean') j[[1]] = quote(median)
  print(j)

  NextMethod(`[`, x)
}
class(a) <- c('dtsurvey', class(a))
a[, mean(v1)]
#> mean(v1)
#> median(v1)
#> Error in `[.data.table`(a, , mean(v1)): j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'j' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..j]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to leverage NextMethod here, as far as I understand it considers the arguments as they were passed. Here's a way to do it :

```r
library(data.table)
a = data.table(v1 = c(1,2,9))
b = copy(a)

"[.dtsurvey" <- function(x, i, j, by, ...){
  mc <- match.call()
  j <- substitute(j)
  j <- do.call(substitute, list(j, list(mean = quote(median))))
  mc[["j"]] <- j
  mc[[1]] <- quote(data.table:::`[.data.table`)
  eval.parent(mc)
}

class(a) <- c('dtsurvey', class(a))
a[, mean(v1)]
#> [1] 2
b[, mean(v1)]
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Alternately :

```
"[.dtsurvey" <- function(x, i, j, by, ...){
  mc <- match.call()
  mc[["j"]] <- do.call(substitute, list(substitute(j), list(mean = quote(median))))
  mc[[1]] <- quote(`[`)
  mc[[2]] <- substitute(as.data.table(x))
  eval.parent(mc)
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I'm curious whether there is a way to do without a direct call on the unexported `data.table:::[.data.table`